# File.readAsDataURL promise does not fullfill

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Good daytime,

I am writing an Ionic App which gets picture file from camera/gallery, writes it into folder (both work) and next must insert in into JSON structure (realized as interface, then converts with JSON.stringify). Right before sending query method reads file into string variable with following code:

```
File.readAsDataURL(imagePath, imageName).then(res=>{
  console.log('It works.');
},err=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

where imagePath is, for example, file:///data/user/0//files/2b0d8450-14dc-44b3-ab28-322c5c2859e4 and imageName is Pasport_Famil_I._stranicza_s_fotografiej.jpg

File exists. Code worked fine just once. But other times promise never been resolved at all.

It doesn't matter "AsWhat" it reads (ArrayBuffer, BinaryString or even Text) and even with strict path division as written in function reference (which I could found only in IDE's pop-up hint, according to which path is File.dataDirectory and file is remained part of fullpath) result is same (its absence).

I'm using OpenJDK 8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1,
Ionic 4.12,
its file plugin version is 5.5.0,
cordova-plugin-file version is 6.0.1

Please "help me, you're my only hope" (C)

Comment: you can get direct base64 string from camera/gallery. so you no need to convert.

Comment: It didn't matter how to read a file to encounter this problem. But anyway reason was in another part of code. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Problem was in forgotten custom code in src/index.html .

Comment: what you mean by custom code ?

Answer (score 0):

Get base64 string from camera/gallery

```
public takePhoto(){
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
}
```